# Overwriting ViewRenderer in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As another step trying to learn Xamarin, I am working a test project on how to draw shapes on a Xamarin multiplatform project (full github code [here](https://github.com/xavierpena/XamarinShapesTest)).

The project is trying to reproduce this other github project (link [here](https://github.com/chrispellett/Xamarin-Forms-Shape)), but using a new blank Xamarin Forms project instead. I then try to put the pieces of the original code together and try understanding them.

Focusing on Android, after putting the code together the shapes are not drawn correctly. I am trying to fix that, and I think it all comes down to this:

A breakpoint in `OnElementChanged` is reached in the original project (see source file [here](https://github.com/chrispellett/Xamarin-Forms-Shape/blob/master/Android/ShapeRenderer.cs)). But a breakpoint in `OnElementChanged` is not reached in my new project (see source file [here](https://github.com/xavierpena/XamarinShapesTest/blob/master/src/ShapesTest/ShapesTest.Droid/ShapeRenderer.cs)).

`SharpRenderer` is present in both .Droid and .iOS projects, but I can't understand how the code is interconnected. I don't seem to find meaningful differences between both codes that help me understand what is going on either.

---

`SharpRenderer` code that is reached in one case but not in the other:

```
public class ShapeRenderer : ViewRenderer<ShapeView, Shape>
{
    public ShapeRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ShapeView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        SetNativeControl(new Shape(Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density, Context)
        {
            ShapeView = Element
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "_See source file here_" is bound to be a broken link at some point. Please add any required and relevant info directly in the question.

Comment: I have added the `ShapeRenderer` code from the .Droid project. Please let me know if any other piece of code would be necessary in the main post (since the error is in the interaction between projects, so it is difficult for me to pinpoint which parts are necessary and which parts are not).

Comment: You're missing this line of code: `[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ShapeView), typeof(ShapeRenderer))]`. It goes above the namespace and is important. `ExportRenderer` alerts Xamarin.Forms use your class to render the specified view class, otherwise Xamarin.Forms will try to use a default renderer.

Comment: @DylanS That was it, thank you so much. And thanks for the explanation as well. Seeing `SharpRenderer` in both .Droid and .iOS I already had a hint that `SharpRenderer` was overwritten, but I didn't know how Xamarin did that. Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing an important line above your renderer class:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(ShapeView), typeof(ShapeRenderer))]
```

This means that your class will be exported and then used b Xamarin Forms Framework to render the `ShapeView`.

For a better understanding you could check documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/).